# Definition of a subalgebra generated by a set, further clarification

Tags: abstract-algebra

In this question [Definition of the subalgebra generated by a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061086/definition-of-the-subalgebra-generated-by-a-set/1061090#1061090), https://math.stackexchange.com/users/31659/seth provides the answer:

Another way to think of the subalgebra of the $A$-algebra $M$ generated by $S\subset M$ is polynomials in elements of $S$ with coefficients in $A$.

I have a follow up question. I'm going to set up the notation I'm using because trying to convert it to the notation used in the original question is confusing me.

Let $K$ be a field. Then, $K[x]$ the collection of polynomials with coefficients in $K$ is a $K$-algebra. Now, am I mistaken in believing that $\{h \in K[x] ~|~ h(x) = a_1x^2 + a_2x^4 + \dots + a_nx^{2n}$ with $a_1, \dots, a_n \in K\}$ is the collection of all finite $K$-linear combinations of all finite products of the elements of $\{x^2\}$?

It certainly seems like a subalgebra to me. It's closed under addition of its own elements, it's closed under products of its own elements, and it's closed under scalar multiplication. It has additive inverses.

However, if I'm to understand the provided answer correctly, the subalgebra generated by $\{x^2\}$ should be $K[x^2]$ which is polynomials in $x^2$. As far as I understand the definition, this would include constant polynomials, which are not included in the set I described above.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to take the empty or trivial product, which returns $1$; that's how you get constant terms. You need to do this for your subalgebra to have a unit.

Comment: Yes you are right. To have the unit in the subalgebra one needs to take care of the constant term of the polynomials! But isn't that the subalgebra generated by $\{1, x^{2}\}$ rather than just $\{x^2\}$. Isn't the set mentioned by Ben Stanley the subalgebra generated by $\{x^2\}$, assuming that subalgebra generated by $\{x^2\}$ is the smallest subalgebra containing $\{x^2\}$?